# Neovim settings get lost

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, neovim

I have neovim installed and this is my init.nvim file

```
call plug#begin('~/.local/share/nvim/plugged')

  Plug 'tyrannicaltoucan/vim-quantum'
  Plug 'mxw/vim-jsx'
  Plug 'pangloss/vim-javascript'
  Plug 'itchyny/lightline.vim'
  Plug 'doums/darcula'

call plug#end()


colorscheme darcula
```

I use `:source init.nvim` and then `:PlugInstall` then everything seems ok and all plugins and themes are installed and the theme is changed too. But when I restart neovim everything is reverted to its original state like nothing has ever happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your `init.vim` at the correct path?

This is the most reliable way to edit the correct file.

Open vim and execute the following command (start by typing `:`).

`:exe "edit" stdpath("config")."/init.vim"`

Comment: thanks for answering  , typing the command gives an error` E117: Unknown function: stdpath
E15: Invalid expression: stdpath("config")."/init.vim"`

Comment: Does nvim not set MYVIMRC? Im surprised

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Nvim (and Vim) sets MYVIMRC if and only if the vimrc (init.vim) is found at the expected location.

Answer (score 1):

I was creating the wrong file , it had to be `init.vim` and i was creating `init.nvim` 
Also I checked again and unbelievably there was no nvim folder in the .config folder at all .
Recreated the file and problem solved.